# SOQL returning last modified contact matching each email address in set

Tags: trigger, soql, bulkification, aggregateresult

I am trying to bulkify a trigger to match transactions with contacts by email address. There are many contacts with duplicate email addresses and getting rid of these duplicates is not an option. I am trying to write a SOQL query that returns only the most recently modified contact record for each email address in a set.

So far the only thing I've come up with is this monstrosity:

```
Set<String> emails = new Set<String>();

emails.add('email_1@example.com');
emails.add('email_2@example.com');

List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Email, Id, LastModifiedDate FROM Contact WHERE Email IN :emails];
List<AggregateResult> agg = [SELECT Email, MAX(LastModifiedDate) FROM Contact WHERE Email IN :emails GROUP BY Email];

Map<String, DateTime> aggMap = new Map<String, DateTime>();

for (AggregateResult res : agg){
    aggMap.put(String.valueOf(res.get('Email')),DateTime.valueOf(res.get('expr0')));
}

List<Contact> keep = new List<Contact>();

for (Contact c : contacts){    
    if(c.LastModifiedDate == aggMap.get(c.Email)){
        keep.add(c);
    }       
}
System.debug(keep);
```

This gets me the desired result, but it seems extremely inefficient. Is there some way to achieve this same result with a single query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done in one query and one for loop:

```
Set<String> emails = new Set<String>();

emails.add('email_1@example.com');
emails.add('email_2@example.com');

Map<String,Contact> lastModifiedByEmail = new Map<String,Contact>();

for(Contact c : [SELECT Id, Email, LastModifiedDate FROM Contact WHERE Email IN :emails]){
    if(lastModifiedByEmail.get(c.Email) == null || lastModifiedByEmail.get(c.Email).LastModifiedDate < c.LastModifiedDate){
        lastModifiedByEmail.put(c.Email,c);
    }
}

System.debug(lastModifiedByEmail.values());
```